# Usage of the =~ operator

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I'm a little confused on VimScript's regex comparison operators.

If I look through `:h =~?` my understanding is that `=~` can be used to do a regex match (with the `?` making it case-insensitive).

But this code prints "no":

```
let s:myVar = "S123"
if s:myVar =~? "^S\d+"
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
endif
```

Am I using the `=~` operator incorrectly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You need `\+` since you're not using magic.
2. You're using `"` instead of `'`. You need to double escape `\`: `\\d`, or use single quotes.

   See [`:h literal-string`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#literal-string):

   ```
   literal-string                                          literal-string E115
   ---------------
   'string'                string constant                 expr-'

   Note that single quotes are used.

   This string is taken as it is.  No backslashes are removed or have a special
   meaning.  The only exception is that two quotes stand for one quote.

   Single quoted strings are useful for patterns, so that backslashes do not need
   to be doubled.  These two commands are equivalent: 
           if a =~ "\\s*"
           if a =~ '\s*'
   ```

So:

```
let s:myVar = "S123"
if s:myVar =~? '^S\d\+'
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
endif
```

This works as expected.

Comment: Ah, thanks. So, I think this is what I was going after: `if s:myVar =~ '\v^S\d+'`

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink you can also tack on case insensitivity to the pattern: `'\v\c^S\d+'`.

Comment: nice. Would that be preferable to using `=~?`

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Depends on how you intend to use it. If you intend to re-use the pattern (keep it in a variable, and do tests in multiple places or something), using `\c` will centralise the case-insensitivity. Useful for code organization, otherwise I don't think there's a difference.